# Solution of system of discrete trigonometric equations

Tags: trigonometry

Given an integer $N$, I am looking to find a real number $t$ to solve the following set of equations:
$$\pi n\equiv t\cos\frac{\pi n}{N}\mod 2\pi,~~~~~~~n=0,1,2,3,\ldots, 2N-1$$
Given an integer $N$, for which real values of $t$ does this system of equations have a solution?

How is the answer modified if I replace the left-hand side with zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

You can write
$$\pi n=t\cos\frac{\pi n}N+2k_n\pi.$$

For $n=0$, this equation simplifies to
$$0=t+2k_0\pi.$$

Then for $n=1$,
$$\pi=-2k_0\pi\cos\frac{\pi}N+2k_1\pi$$

so that

$$\cos\frac\pi N=\frac{2k_1-1}{2k_0}.$$

There are very few fractions of $\pi$ having a rational cosine...